# What is the shortcut to Hide Active Tool Windows in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, android-studio-3.0

In Android Studio, when we want to hide active tool windows, we could see that in the menu. However I can't understand the shortcut symbol. Shift + WHAT? (as show in diagram below)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It is  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd>

Tested on Windows and Ubuntu, 
Change it if you want.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts), you will have to use  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

> Hide active or last active tool window:

```
Shift + Esc
```

Answer (score 3):

The shortcut for hiding the active tool windows is
[Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html)
   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Esc</kbd>